# Current week in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

good morning, I'm in the middle of a project and I'm stuck on finding a way to return every day of the current week in a list. It would be something like this:

```
week=[ '2022-06-07' , '2022-06-08' , '2022-06-09' , '' , '...']
```

I would be very grateful if you could explain to me a way to obtain this result,,, thanks

Comment: You find the start of the week you are in, then add single days to it seven times ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shorten this but I wrote it out like this for clarity.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_obj = datetime(2022, 6, 7)  # Today, Tuesday
monday = date_obj - timedelta(days=date_obj.weekday())  # assuming start of week is Monday
week = []
for i in range(7):
    week.append((monday + timedelta(days=i)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
print(week)
```

Output:

```
# Monday 6/6 to Sunday 6/12
['2022-06-06', '2022-06-07', '2022-06-08', '2022-06-09', '2022-06-10', '2022-06-11', '2022-06-12']
```